# Как исключить роутер в Nuxt 3 из проекта, что бы не выдавало ошибку 404?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue3, vue-router

Есть проект на **nuxt 3**, в котором прописаны роуты вручную в файле `router.options.ts` к примеру так (и они работают):

```
// Посты блога
{
  name: 'postsIndex',
  path: '/posts',
  component: () => import('~/pages/posts/index.vue').then((r) => r.default || r),
},
{
  name: 'post',
  path: '/:id-post',
  component: () => import('~/pages/posts/[id].vue').then((r) => r.default || r),
}
```

Так же есть папка с файлами `.html` внутри проекта к примеру `/.projects/`

**Суть**: я обращаюсь по адресу `domain.com/.projects/index.html` и получаю ошибку 404 от nuxt 3.

**Вопрос**: Как исключить папку `/.projects/` и все подпапки и файлы, что бы nuxt не реагировал на их содержимое? И при этом отобразился нужный `.html` файл?

PS: если, что на сервере стоит `nginx`